# How do you find the height of a triangle given $3$ angles and the base side? Image given.

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

[image: This question has me absolutely stumped. This is the image of the question, how can I work out $x$? I've been doing a variety of attempts but I just cant get it.]

This question has me absolutely stumped. This is the image of the question, how can I work out $x$? I've been doing a variety of attempts but I just cant get it.

Comment: You can use the [Law of Sines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) to find one of the other side lengths. Then it should be an easy matter to find $x$ using one of the trig functions.

Answer (score 5):

Call the side opposite $33^\circ$ as $a$. Therefore we have: $$\dfrac {x}{a}=\sin 25^\circ$$

and from the [sine rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_rule) for the triangle we know that: $$\dfrac {20}{\sin 122^\circ}=\dfrac {a}{\sin 33^\circ}$$

Therefore from the above two equations we have $x=\dfrac{20\times\sin 33^\circ \times \sin 25^\circ}{\sin 122^\circ} $, or $$x\approx5.428336828982414$$

Comment: To compare our answers: $$\begin{align}\frac1{\cot(33^\circ)+\cot(25^\circ)} &=\frac{\sin(33^\circ)\sin(25^\circ)}{\cos(33^\circ)\sin(25^\circ)+\cos(25^\circ)\sin(33^\circ)}\\[4pt] &=\frac{\sin(33^\circ)\sin(25^\circ)}{\sin(58^\circ)}\\[4pt] &=\frac{\sin(33^\circ)\sin(25^\circ)}{\sin(122^\circ)}\end{align}$$

Comment: @robjohn, both of us have tried different things which are essentially the same... The question was quite elementary though...

Comment: Agreed. I was just showing how the answers were the same even though they look quite different.

Answer (score 5):

Another approach is to note that
$$
x\cot(33^\circ)+x\cot(25^\circ)=20
$$
to get
$$
\begin{align}
x
&=\frac{20}{\cot(33^\circ)+\cot(25^\circ)}\\[4pt]
&\approx5.42833368289824
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Simple, since sine rule, so $$\frac{a}{\sin(A)}=\frac{b}{\sin(B)}=\frac{c}{\sin(C)}$$ and the diagonal opposing 33° can be found by $$a=\frac{20\cdot \sin33}{\sin122}=12.844...$$ then, we use sine to find the height $$\frac{h}{12.844...}=\sin25$$and boom, $$h=12.844...\cdot \sin25=5.428...$$

Answer (score 0):

[problem statement, with construction](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EkBJU.png)

I prefer to think of it this way:
The base of the overall triangle can be composed of segments S and T, where:

```
20 = S + T
```

Then, using tan(A) = opposite side/adjacent side:

```
tan(25) =X/S
tan(33) =X/T
```

X is a common side, so, X = X

```
S*tan(25)  = T * tan(33)
```

But

```
T = B - S
```

so the rest is just algebra

```
S*tan(25) = (B-S)*tan(33)
S*tan(25) = B*tan(33) - S*tan(33)
S*tan(25) + S*tan(33) = B*tan(33)
S(tan(25) + tan(33)) = B*tan(33)
S = B * (tan(33)/(tan(25) + tan(33))

S = (20 * .649407)/(.466307+.649407)
S = 11.641099
```

Going back to tan(25) = X/S

```
X = S * tan(25)
X = 11.641099 * .466307
X = 5.42833
```