# Calculate height of triangle given angle and base

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

[image]

I need to calculate the height of $x$ in my triangle and I know the base as well as the inner angles. I've used the following equation to try calculate it based off this answer here:

[How do you find the height of a triangle given $3$ angles and the base side? Image given.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674907/how-do-you-find-the-height-of-a-triangle-given-3-angles-and-the-base-side-ima)

The equation that I got based off that answer was this:

$$x = \frac{1000  \sin(90)  \sin(5)}{  \sin(85)}$$

this gives me a value of around $4000$ which can't be right so not sure where i've gone wrong here?

Comment: $x=1000\tan 5^{\circ}$

Comment: Your expression, if evaluated correctly, should be around $87.5$, not $4000$. Be sure that whatever calculator you’re using is set for degrees, not radians.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you were trying to use the Law of Sines. That rule is often presented as: $$\frac{\sin A}{a}=\frac{\sin B}{b}=\frac{\sin C}{c},$$ which makes it look like one formula involving $a$ and $b$ and $c$, but it is only applied to two at a time. In this case, we're not worried about $a$, so we can ignore both it and the right angle. Then we have: $$\frac{\sin 5^\circ}{x}=\frac{\sin 85^\circ}{1000},$$ which can be solved for $x$.

---

Keep in mind, though, the Law of Sines is not the easiest way to approach this problem. When the triangle has a right angle, we can directly relate sides and angles using the right-triangle definitions of sine, cosine and tangent:

- $\sin \theta=\frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{hypotenuse}}$
- $\cos \theta=\frac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{hypotenuse}}$
- $\tan \theta=\frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}}$

You pick the one that applies to your problem, and plug in: Here we have one leg of the right triangle, and we want the other, so we use tangent: $$\tan 5^\circ=\frac{x}{1000}$$

---

If you're working with a triangle that's not a right triangle, then $\sin$ is often the most useful function for finding heights, but that's another question.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $\tan 5 ^{\circ}=\frac{x}{1000}$